# ASP.Net Core 2 error handling: How to return formatted exception details in Http Response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, error-handling, asp.net-core-2.0

I am looking for a way to return the details of any exception that occur when calling a method of my web API.

By default in production environment, error 500 "Internal Server Error" is the only information returned by the API.

It is a private API that is not published over the internet, and the caller application needs to get and store all details in case of exception.

The exception details could be **JSON** formatted in the **HttpResponse** content, allowing the caller to read the ***Message*** attribute, and the ***StackTraceString*** attribute of the exception (No HTTP page like *UseDeveloperExceptionPage* configuration).

Currently the default Startup Configure method is:

```
public class Startup
{   
    [...]

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddNLog();
        env.ConfigureNLog(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "nlog.config"));

        if ( env.IsDevelopment() )
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        else
            app.UseStatusCodePages();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could write a custom middleware, which intercepts all exceptions and returns them to the caller:

```
public class ExceptionHandler
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ExceptionHandler(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        var response = context.Response;
        response.ContentType = "application/json";
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        await response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            // customize as you need
            error = new
            {
                message = exception.Message,
                exception = exception.GetType().Name
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

and register it in your Startup Configure method:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
else
   app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandler>();
```

Comment: It works perfectly, +1. We should have that kind of example in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling

Comment: @CommonGuy - where would you store this class?  Do you put it in a Models directory or what is the recommended practice?

Comment: Depends on how you structure your project. I personally have folders for each layer (Controller, Repository, ...), so I put this class in a Middleware folder

Comment: @CommonGuy - So you've got a folder called "Middleware" with this in it - seems reasonable.  I do have a folder for each layer, controller, repository, service, but I did not have a Middleware folder.

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively to middleware, you can create ActionFilterAttribute and change IActionResult

Here is simple example attribuet that for all unhandled exceptions returns 400 Bad request with Exception method.

```
public class MyUnhandledExceptionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{        
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {           
        context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.Exception.Message);
    }
}
```

You then register it in startup's ConfigureServices method like this

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(MyUnhandledExceptionFilter));
        })
```

This only catches exceptions that reached MVC, which in most cases is what you need

Comment: Nice solution +1, it works. But how can we make this behavior depend on the environment ?

Comment: @abreneliere, simply inject IHostingEnvironment into Startup's constructor and save the reference. Or you could use environment based startup class. Check this docs for more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments

Answer (score 1):

Remember to add it before UseMvc (or UseRouting in .Net Core 3) as order is important!!!!!

```
        app.UseRouting ();
        app.UseMiddleware (typeof (ErrorHandlingMiddleware));
```