# Get exception details

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I would like to have a function that when an exception is given to it, it will extract all the information about that exception and then write it to a database.

Before going to .NET Core 2, I was able to do this in the following manner:

```
var details = new ErrorDetails();
if (ex == null) return details;
var st = new StackTrace(ex, true);
var frames = st.GetFrames();
if (frames != null && frames.Length > 0)
{
    var errorDetails = frames.Select(frame => new ErrorDetails
    {
        FileName = frame.GetFileName(),
        LineNumber = frame.GetFileLineNumber().ToString(),
        MethodName = frame.GetMethod().Name,
        ClassName = frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType.FullName
    });

    return errorDetails.FirstOrDefault();
}
return details;
```

Ever since switching my project to .NET Core 2, this code comes back with most of this information being null/default; I took a look at the frames that I extract, and they don't have the information anymore. For things like `FileName` and `LineNumber`, the values are null. For things like `MethodName` and `ClassName`, the value is there but wrong.

I would crash my project with code such as this:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public string ErrorHandling()
    {
        var a = int.Parse("fail parsing on purpose");
        return a.ToString();
    }
}
```

The value for `MethodName` ends up being `StringToNumber` and for `ClassName` is `System.Number`

I can't seem to find any information on the web as to why this is and how I can go about retrieving the details for the exception.

EDIT:

I thought it might also be useful to list how I am handling exceptions. I have written a custom middleware error exception handler very similar to the one in this SO post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48625298/2371128

EDIT 2:
This is being run in DEBUG mode.

Comment: _"most of the information"_ - do you mean these four properties? Half of them (file name and line number) is null/default even in .NET Framework if there is no .pdb file or the assembly is a release build.

Comment: This is happening in debug, and yes, for now, I mean those 4 properties. I'd like to keep it simple.

Comment: could you post your custom middleware ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your Startup.cs

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(
         options =>
         {
             options.Run(
             async context =>
             {
                 var ex = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                 if (ex != null)
                 {
                     try
                     {
                         await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () =>
                          {
                              var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DBContext>();
                              builder.UseSqlServer(_config["ConnectionStrings:ContextConnection"]);
                              var _context = new DBContext(_config, builder.Options, httpContextAccessor);
                              //Log to DB
                              await repository.LogError(_context, ex.Error.Message, $"{ex.Error.InnerException?.Message}<br/>{ex.Error.StackTrace}");
                          });

                     }
                     finally
                     {
                         //Optional
                         await repository.SendMailToAdmin(ex.Error.Message, $"{ex.Error.InnerException?.Message}<br/>{ex.Error.StackTrace}");
                     }

                     context.Response.Redirect("/app/Errors/500");
                 }
             });
         }
        );
```

//ErrorLog.cs

```
 public class ErrorLog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Error { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(4000)]
    public string Details { get; set; }

    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding how this gets me `LineNumber` or `MethodName` I already have error handling setup in place, its almost identical to the one I linked in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```
public class ExceptionDetail
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public string InnerExceptionMessage { get; set; }

    public string StackTrace { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> StackTraceLines { get; set; }

    public string Target { get; set; }

    public string Source { get; set; }
}


var exDetail = new ExceptionDetail
{
    Message = exception.Message,
    InnerExceptionMessage = exception.InnerException?.Message,
    Source = exception.Source,
    StackTrace = exception.StackTrace,
    StackTraceLines = exception.StackTrace.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList(),
    Target = exception.TargetSite.ToString()
};
```

Comment: I'm not understanding how this is able to pull out details that I am looking for, such as `LineNumber` or `MethodName`